# How can I make a deepClone() that preserves the type of its input?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to use generics to create a `deepClone()` function that returns the same type as it was passed. It should take any object (including arrays) and return a deep clone with the same type as the input.

So far I've read the [generics docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and come up with:

```
const deepClone = <T extends Record<string, unknown> | Array<unknown>>(object: T): T => {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
};

interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const Steve: Person = {
  name: "Steve",
  age: 21,
};

const evilSteve = deepClone(Steve);
```

However VS Code shows the type of `evilSteve` as:

```
const evilSteve: Record<string, unknown> | unknown[]
```

I am trying to make it show:

```
const evilSteve: Person
```

How can I make the function return the same type as the input?

Comment: Your problem isn't the output type, it's that `Steve` of the type `Person` (an interface) is not assignable to `Record<string, unknown> | unknown[]` so there's an error on the input.  You should probably just write `T extends object` instead like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxB5Kw) and the problem will go away.  If that meets your needs I can write up an answer.  If not, please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: Why not just use `<T>`?

Comment: Oh, yeah, if you're going to constrain the input it should probably be some provably JSON-like type like [this example shows](https://tsplay.dev/N542Zw).  Does that help?  But that's not really the question you're asking about, I guess.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can't work out how to message you, but TypeScript types aren't the same as JS types (eg `typeof`) and I wanted to be explicit about that.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! FYI I get a warning `Don't use `Function` as a type. The `Function` type accepts any function-like value.` using that example, though it does solve the question.

Comment: Your warning is almost certainly from a linter and not from TypeScript itself.  It's probably the questionably helpful ban-types from eslint, which often complains about types without caring about context.  `extends object` and `extends Function` should be just fine.  If you ever create a value of type `object` or `Function` that would be more problematic, but the linter complains regardless of how it's used.

Comment: Anyway, @TitianCernicovaDragomir has answered your question as asked, so I'll probably bow out.  Some other question somewhere asking about validating a value as JSON would be more appropriate for the code I posted above.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @jcalz I kinda like the simplicity of your answer though I do get the JSON validation bit. I've upvoted all your comments as a bit of a thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea. The constraint of `Record<string, unknown>` will require an index signature in `Person`, as the error shows in this [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=36&pln=1&pc=53#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwQBwMIBtwJgXhgHgBUYEAPKBMOCGAJQVACc59pGBLMAcwBoYBXMAGswIAO5gAfDAA+MAIKNGAQwCe+QSPFTJAChAAjAFYMoALhiEAlBeI5pAbwBQMGIwRR+jMDABSAZQB5ADkAOmRlRggEXQCQ0LZOLnYAM1V9Y1MrKwBuJwBfPKdOCkYU5WBsAAUEKPAYZ1cwZQBbBAtE7jzXZS52mDB+FoNavPynJ1BIWH8KADd+mrqfPEaB1v6AIlmEBc2eFxhe-oAmAEYDwomp6BI59nQdhdx4JDRMMBinhFygA)

A constraint of `Record<string, any>` or just `object` does what you expect it to:

```
const deepClone = <T extends Record<string, any> | Array<unknown>>(object: T): T => {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwQBwMIBtwJgXhgHgBUYEAPKBMOCGAJQVACc59pGBLMAcwBoYBDMAE8AfDAA+MAIKNG-IfgCuYANZgQAdzAiRAChAAjAFYMoALhiEAlBeI4xAbwBQMGIwRRFjMDABSAZQB5ADkAOmR+RggEXQCQ0LZOLnYAMyF9Y1MrKwBuJwBfPKdOCkYU-mBsAAUEKPAYZ1cwfgBbBAtE7jzXfi52mDBFFoNavPynJ1BIWH8KADd+mrqfPEaB1v6AIlmEBc2eFwE+iwAmAEYDwomp6BI59nQdhdx4JDRMMBinhFygA)

Note: `Record<string, any>` has special treatment, and basically means any object type, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41746)

Comment: `const evilSteve: Person` perfect!

Comment: Why `any` for object values and `unknown` for array items?

Comment: `Record<string, any>` has special treatment, I can't find the GH issue where this is stated but it does.

Comment: @mikemaccana found the reference for that. Added it

Comment: Wouldn't `Record<string, unknown>` make more sense? Edit: nope it doesn't work, the type will be wrong....